# Does a texture mask need to be the same size as the base texture?

Tags: textures, graphics

new to game development here. I am working with an experienced 3D modeler and following some tutorials on texture mapping. Apologies if this is not the appropriate question for this forum, but this is more about understanding what is happening under the hood than a specific code question.

How can a texture mask be a different size from the base texture of the mesh it's trying to cover? Let me provide these two images I took from Google as an example. Imagine the first image was 2x as large as the mask. In reality though, these images are also slightly different sizes. If they are not the same size, how would the mask know to scale up and mask the right part?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a pixel shader samples a texture (regardless of what kind of texture), it usually does so using the UV coordinates interpolated between the UV coordinates of the vertices of the polygon. The result is a pair of floating point values between 0 and 1. It then uses those coordinates to get the color value of the texture at that point, with 0:0 being the upper left corner of the texture and 1:1 being the lower right. Those floating point coordinates are unlikely to match to one pixel exactly. Most of the time they will be somewhere between those pixels. Which is where different interpolation algorithms are being used.

That means it is not strictly necessary for textures used within the same material to all have the same resolution or even the same aspect ratio. Interpolation will take care of it. This can be useful when you run into GPU-RAM limits and need to prioritize where to save on texture resolution. Using lower resolutions for some texture types is often a lot less noticeable than for others. For example a high-resolution albedo texture can often get away with a much lower resolution normal map without much perceived loss in visual fidelity.

However, in a case like this, where one texture is directly applied to another, it would be very advisable to make them the same size regardless. It makes the design process a lot easier. The texture artist can overlay both textures in an image editor as separate layers and easily make sure they fit exactly. You are also avoiding artifacts at the border of the texture mask which come from the interpolation algorithms not getting the same results for both textures due to the different pixel resolutions. But that does of course depend on the artists workflow. If they are the kind of artist who never edits textures in 2d and only ever texture-paints on a 3d model, then they might never notice those problems.